# Convert list of dict into dict with values as keys

Tags: python, dictionary

Given the dictionary:

```
dictData = [{'aaa': 'aaa_value1', 'bbb': 'bbb_value1', 'ccc': 'ccc_value1'}, 
            {'aaa': 'aaa_value1', 'bbb': 'bbb_value2', 'ccc': 'ccc_value2'},
            {'aaa': 'aaa_value2', 'bbb': 'bbb_value3', 'ccc': 'ccc_value3'}]
```

I want this:

```
   newdictData=[{'aaa_value1':[(bbb_value1,ccc_value1),(bbb_value2, ccc_value2)],
                {'aaa_value2':[(bbb_value3,ccc_value3)],
```

Comment: Would help to provide comment for down voting so I can understand. Obviously I am not an expert at formatting things at stack over flow..thank you

Comment: I'm not the down-voter, but people like to see what you've attempted. Right now it looks like you're just expecting us to solve your problem without you even trying to.

Comment: dicts are unordered, how the key is defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
dictData = [{'aaa': 'aaa_value1', 'bbb': 'bbb_value1', 'ccc': 'ccc_value1'}, 
        {'aaa': 'aaa_value1', 'bbb': 'bbb_value2', 'ccc': 'ccc_value2'},
        {'aaa': 'aaa_value2', 'bbb': 'bbb_value3', 'ccc': 'ccc_value3'}]
for i in dictData:
    the_vals = sorted(i.values())
    d[the_vals[0]].append(the_vals[1:])
print(dict(d))
```

Output:

```
{'aaa_value1': [['bbb_value1', 'ccc_value1'], ['bbb_value2', 'ccc_value2']], 'aaa_value2': [['bbb_value3', 'ccc_value3']]}
```

Comment: You shouldn't rely o the order of `values()`, also this will only work on Python 2, so you **really** shouldn't rely on the order of values. Also, calling values twice is needlessly inefficient.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I believe I found a solution to that issue. Please see my recent edit.